# prevent bind mount on login if mounted

Tags: linux, mount, util-linux

At login, a bind mount is created. In `~/.pam_mount.conf.xml`:

```
  <volume options="bind" user="phg" mountpoint="/nix" path="/store/nix" />
```

This needs to be done only once per boot. Note that I do not have
access to the fstab or systemd mounts.

The bind mount itself works. However, *it is being executed on
every login*. Since I can have dozens, hundreds of logins to the
box via SSH, this fills up the mount table rather quickly. Just
minutes ago the box was rendered unusable due to resource
exhaustion because of it.

Detecting an existing bind mount is easy but with *pam_mount.so*
I don’t see a means to make the mount depend on the result of,
say a script.

Hence my question:

- How can I prevent the bind mount from being executed more than
  once, **or**
- how can I make repeated bind mounts a no-op so as to prevent mounts
  from accumulating?

See also: https://github.com/karelzak/util-linux/issues/448

Comment: `pam_exec` could do it, but it sounds like you can't change the PAM configuration either.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. Sadly, *pam_exec* is not available on this system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wonder if you are using systemd (mount propagation by default). It seems to more than double the number of bind mounts each time. Maybe it behaves better with `private` in the mount options... Ah.  I see you can write `unbindable` as an option to mount. If it accepts that, then it could answer your question.  So long as `pam_mount` allows a mount to fail and does not abort the login.

---

I notice that for some reason, your `pam_mount` does not seem to be working as it is designed.

pam_mount keeps a "reference count" of your mounts.  For example, if you have two active logins at once, the filesystem should only be mounted once.  It is unmounted after both sessions log out.

If you are stopping the filesystem from being unmounted at logout time, you are abusing pam_mount.  Be aware that it might change in future in some way which breaks your setup.

Comment: *So long as pam_mount allows a mount to fail and does not abort the login*  – this should be possible with the *nofail* option, shouldn’t it?

Comment: *pam_mount keeps a "reference count" of your mounts. For example, if you have two active logins at once, the filesystem should only be mounted once. It is unmounted after both sessions log out.* – the first part does not agree with my observation; the latter is trivial to explain: over a work day, tons of SSH sessions accumulate to that system, I rarely close them (working with a master connection is too fragile in my experience).

Comment: @phg I think `nofail` only applies to `mount -a` (or systemd equivalent).

Answer (score 1):

After going through the *pam_mount* code I believe I know what is
going on. The situation arises mainly from two issues:

- The *pam_mount* approach to detecting already mounted volumes
  is too simplistic.
- The kernel will happily stack repeated bind mounts on top of
  one another even if source path and mountpoint are the same.

From `mount.c` in the *pam_mount* repo:

```
128         xcmp = fstype2_icase(vpt->type) ? strcasecmp : strcmp;
129         if (source != NULL)
130                 result = xcmp(vpt->volume, source) == 0;
131         if (target != NULL)
132                 result &= strcmp(vpt->mountpoint, target) == 0;
```

That’s it. The values for *source* and *target* are supplied by
*libmount* from util-linux. Unfortunately, *libmount* is able to
determine the original source path of a bind mount only if it
appears in `/run/mount/utab`. PAM mountpoints don’t. Thus it’s
not sufficient for extending the above check.

However, for the bind mount

```
<volume
  options="bind,nodev,exec,nosuid"
  user="yourstruly"
  mountpoint="/nix"
  path="/mnt/local/nix"
  />
```

the kernel generates an entry in `/proc/mounts` as follows:

```
/dev/mapper/VolGroup00-local /nix ext4 rw,relatime 0 0
```

where the source obviously doesn’t match the path we specified in
the mount(8) command line. Instead, it gives the underlying
volume as the source, causing the check by *pam_mount* to fail.

The source path information is lost. A bit better is
`/proc/self/mountinfo`:

```
934 654 253:6 /nix /nix rw,relatime shared:33 - ext4 /dev/mapper/VolGroup00-local rw
```

Also according to the
[libmount source](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/utils/util-linux/util-linux.git/tree/libmount/src/mountP.h?id=2c37ca7c4b766d08ed604eac17fea42e86916c2d#n187)
the *first* `/nix` (arg index 4) corresponds to the “root of
the mount within the FS”. (The second one is the mountpoint in
VFS.) **Thus, the original path passed to *mount(8)* is
substituted by the location inside the volume.** With the volume
being mounted at `/mnt/local` we end up with merely `/nix`.
This value can be queried using an API (`mnt_table_get_fs_root()`)
but it’s useless for *pam_mount* because the latter doesn’t strip
the mountpoint from the source value when performing the check.